# How to read and change body of Response into overided OnActionExecuted method of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to append some info to each JSON answer of every action of controller. For this, I make base controller inherited from standard MVC `Controller` class.
I try like this. But I catch `ArgumentException` with message like this "Stream was not readable." Probably stream was closed when `ActionResult` object wrote data to body. What can I do?

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    var respApi = new ResponseApiDTO();
    respApi.Comment = "You could!!!";
    JObject jRespApi = JObject.FromObject(respApi);
    Stream bodyStream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
    JObject jbody;

    context.Result = Json(jbody);
    using( var rd = new StreamReader(bodyStream))
    {
        string bodyText = rd.ReadToEnd();
        jbody = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
        jbody.Add(jRespApi);
        context.Result = Json(jbody);
    }
}
```

Comment: Underline Body property is  FrameResponseStream class. The fact is that it does not implement the read methods.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a solution. We need to replace the Body stream with `MemoryStream` object while executing MVC step in pipeline. And then we must return original stream object object into `Response.Body`.

```
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class BufferedResponseBodyExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseBufferedResponseBody(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (var bufferStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var orgBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
                context.Response.Body = bufferStream;

                await next();//there is running MVC
                   
                bufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await bufferStream.CopyToAsync(orgBodyStream);    
                context.Response.Body = orgBodyStream;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then include this into the pipline. Class Startup, method Configure.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{   
    ...
    app.UseBufferedResponseBody();
    app.UseMvc();           
    ...
}
```

And after replacing responses body stream you can read and modify body contents via Result Filter.

```
 public class ResultFilterAttribute : Attribute, IResultFilter
 {
     public async void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
     {
         Stream bodyStream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
         bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         string bodyText = rd.ReadToEnd();
     }
 }
```

This attribute must be aplied to the target Controller class.

Comment: where does `rd` come from in your last code box